# Enable ping and SSH from Devstack host to guests

Tags: linux, openstack

I have installed OpenStack using devstack in my machine. After fresh install it automatically created two interfaces

```
br-ex
virbr0
```

I launched an Ubuntu instance. I can login to console. I set up IP address manually. I have no idea why the machine did not get the IP address from DHCP? The ip address of the instance is

```
172.24.4.11
```

and it has internet connection and also the gateway (172.24.4.1) can ping from inside the instance. But I cannot ping or SSH to guest from devstack host!
I search and everybody tell run something like the following:

```
$ nova secgroup-add-rule default icmp -1 -1 0.0.0.0/0
$ nova secgroup-add-rule default tcp 22 22 0.0.0.0/0
```

But when I run the above command I get the error:

```
error: argument <subcommand>: invalid choice: 'secgroup-add-rule'
```

I don't know how should I add a security rule with nova! I have installed the latest stable version of Openstack Victoria

`Update:`
I added the required rules via Openstack Panel --> Network --> Security Groups. But I wonder to know how can I manipulate the rules using CLI.

Comment: To which network did you connect the instance? The address you set manually is a floating IP address. This makes me wonder if the instance is connected to the public network. There is no DHCP server on Devstack's public network.

Comment: Your second question is about security groups. I think the old nova secgroup commands were obsoleted a year or two ago. Use the `openstack` command for manipulating security groups: https://docs.openstack.org/newton/user-guide/cli-nova-configure-access-security-for-instances.html#create-and-manage-security-group-rules.

Comment: @berndbausch Yes there is no DHCP on public network. I assign the IP address (172.24.4.11) manually. I visit the link but it also manipulates the rules with nova! It uses ```openstack ```  just for list, create and delete. May you please  give me an example of how to add  ICMP to default security group with ```openstack``` command. Thanks

Comment: Why do you manually assign an external IP to the instance?

Comment: `openstack security group rule create --proto icmp SECGROUP`. Sorry, I had not seen that the user guide was that outdated.

Comment: Why do you manually assign an external IP to the instance? In fact the ip address was assigned to the instance and could be seen in the Panel, but it was not configured on the vm. I logged in via console and manually set up the IP address inside the machine.

Comment: You ask "I have no idea why the machine did not get the IP address from DHCP?". The answer is most probably because you attach the instance to Devstack's public network, which has no DHCP server.

Comment: Yes I attached two interfaces; public and private. I got that: Public network has no DHCP. And thanks for the security rule too. It works. what about the SSH rule? I replaced ```ssh``` with ```icmp``` but I get error!

Comment: You have to open a port: `openstack security group rule create --proto tcp --port 22 SECGROUP`. See also https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/command-objects/security-group-rule.html#security-group-rule-create.

Comment: @berndbausch Great. Thanks. I will accept as the best answer if you post your comments as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DHCP is normally not enabled on Devstack's public network. It seems that OP attaches the instance there.

To manage security group rules on the command line, see the [openstack client documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/command-objects/security-group-rule.html). To create ICMP and SSH rules:

```
openstack security group rule create --proto icmp SECGROUPNAME
openstack security group rule create --proto tcp --dst-port 22 SECGROUPNAME
```